# Highcharts values in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to align the values shown on the right of the bar chart *(34.4, 21.8, 20.1 etc.)* to the far side of the chart as shown in the diagrams below:

Original:
[image: Original Image]

Desired Right Alignment of Values:
[image: Desired]

I am using HighCharts, my code is:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80],
                inverted: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2008'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Tokyo',
                    'Jakarta',
                    'New York',
                    'Seoul',
                    'Manila',
                    'Mumbai',
                    'Sao Paulo',
                    'Mexico City',
                    'Dehli',
                    'Osaka',
                    'Cairo',
                    'Kolkata',
                    'Los Angeles',
                    'Shanghai',
                    'Moscow',
                    'Beijing',
                    'Buenos Aires',
                    'Guangzhou',
                    'Shenzhen',
                    'Istanbul'
                ],
                labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        'Population in 2008: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +
                        ' millions';
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Population',
                data: [34.4, 21.8, 20.1, 20, 19.6, 19.5, 19.1, 18.4, 18,
                    17.3, 16.8, 15, 14.7, 14.5, 13.3, 12.8, 12.4, 11.8,
                    11.7, 11.2],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: 'Black',
                    align: 'right',
                    //x: parseFloat(this.y) + 10,
                    x: 40,
                    y: 10,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y;
                    },
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

I have a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SL68H/1/)

Comment: Please be clearer on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Do you want the dataLabels to be all the way against the right-most edge of the chart?

Comment: update: image added to the question

Comment: it would be ok if labels will be on the right of the graph, without dependency on lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do it using it's API yet.
But the following code can do it for you:

// `#container` is your chart container id

```
$('#container .highcharts-data-labels g').attr('transform', function(i, value) {
    return value.replace(/\d+/, chart.containerWidth - 150);
});
```

If you inspect your chart content you'll see that each label has `transform` attr, this is used to place the labels into the chart, so the code above replace the first parameter(`x`) of it's attr.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SL68H/12/)

Comment: if I resize the window the labels come back to lines, how can I prevent this?

Comment: is it possible to add second y axes to the right? and put the labels with values there. I don't need the second y line to appear

Comment: @user1032946 The problem is that your chart's inverted, so the other yAxis labels will appear on the top of the chart and not on the right side.

Comment: if I resize the window the labels come back to lines, how can I prevent this?

Comment: You have to do the same on the `redraw` event, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SL68H/14/

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for one of my projects. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kashyap02004/veJ38/.

basically you have to render the values like this :

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 645, 203, 20]
    }]
},
```

// this is where all the magic happens

```
function (chart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
        var point = chart.series[0].data[i];

        var text = chart.renderer.text(
        point.y, // you can display any property on that object.
        //tweek these values to align it
        chart.plotLeft + chart.plotSizeY - 30,
        chart.plotHeight - point.barX + 45).attr({
            zIndex: 5,
            fill: '#666679',
        }).add();
    }
});
```